# Issue with jQuery keydown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue with this simple jQuery code.

I have attached the HTML structure as well,

The code is setting focus to the input field fine if I make a click anywhere on the div with id "scroll-pane", but if I click anywhere else in the screen, for example, code above the div id "scroll-pane", it doesnt bring the focus. what am I doing wrong here?

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('#outerBody').keydown(function() {
      $('#serialCode').focus();      
    });
});
</script>

<center id="outerbody">
<table id="tab1" class="Tab1" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td width="60"></td>
    <td width="113"><p align="center">C</td>
    <td width="105">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table  id="tab2" class="Tab2" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>A </td>
    <td>B </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="serialCode" class="serialCode" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="scroll-pane" class="scroll-pane">

</div>
```

Comment: Try not using `<center>` tags and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not attach the keydown event to the entire document window?

```
$(document).keydown(function() {
  $("#serialCode").focus();
});​
```

This might work, or help you figure it out.

view: http://jsbin.com/iwuwa4 
edit: http://jsbin.com/iwuwa4/edit

Answer (score 1):

Either close the  tag (`</center>`), or put the "outerBody" class on a div, Or:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('#tab1,#tab2,#scroll-pane').keydown(function() {
      $('#serialCode').focus();      
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this approach,  $('#tab1,#tab2,#scroll-pane').keydown(function() {
 Didnt work either, focus is only going to input field, if I click inside the DIV

Comment: your problem is keydown doesn't trigger for a context unless you are focused on an element that can have the focus on that context, I'm sure if you add an input to one of the tables and press a key on it, it will take you to the serial code input

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#serialCode')[0].focus();`

Calling `focus` on the jQuery object fires events associated with `focus`. You need to call focus on the dom element.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I didnt get your reply. Could you please explain again.

Comment: Hi Stefan, just tried your solution, it didnt work for me. My requirement is, as soon as user presses a key, that keys value should be shown in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

bind focus event on document.

Comment: Hi Praveen, something like this? $.keydown(function() {
      $('#inputScanner').focus();      
      });

Comment: Nah. He means $(document).keydown(). You'll likely still need to modify your call to focus as I showed in my post.